# Export Google Reminders

Tags: inbox-by-gmail, google-calendar-reminders

Is there a way to export Google reminders?

In Google ecosystem, these reminders are everywhere. In Google Calendar, Google Inbox, Google Keep, Google Now, etc.

But is there a way to export/ sync these reminders to any outside service/ provider?

Answer (score 3):

For Inbox Reminders, I found a way to at least export their urls to a readable plain text list, using the javascript console. I've used the snippet below:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('bV dj')).map(function(i){ return decodeURIComponent(i.href.replace(/^.*url\?q=([^&]*)&.*$/,'$1')) })
```

Which prints a comma-separated list of urls that I can copy and paste elsewhere.

Comment: What are "inbox" reminders?  I've only got reminders in the actual Calendar and when I paste this into the console it returns an empty array, even when there are lots of reminders showing on the screen.

Comment: I meant Google Inbox Reminders: https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6062813?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

I understand that Google is discontinuing the product on March 2019.

Comment: Google support suggests exporting reminders data with Google Takeout. See https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/9117840?hl=en. Note that HTML is the only available export format.

Answer (score 0):

I could export the content of all reminders text, URL or both from the developer console with

```
JSON.stringify(Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('div.bg.summTaskTitle > span')).map(i => i.innerText))
```